# Hibernate - Mapping identical columns

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a source table like:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_X
(
    ID decimal(20) NOT NULL,
    COL_A smallint NOT NULL,
    COL_B decimal(1,0) NOT NULL,
    COL1 int DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    COL2 int DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    .
    .
    .
    COL100 int DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
)
```

As you see, there are a lot of identical columns following a naming pattern. Is it possible to map this table to an entity class so these repeated columns can be represented in a collection/array?

Comment: This smells of a bad database design to me. What do you need one hundred near identical columns for?

Comment: Table design is of course bad. I guess the motivation is to see all data in a row. But I need to use this as a source table.

Comment: You have 100 of column same type? What is the use of this? is this your database design? looking very odd.

Comment: Try to create just one varchar field, and add all your values with a separator like "|" or "," or whatever you want, but have 100 columns on your table it´s definitely wrong.

Comment: Actually over 300 :) If there won't be a practical answer, I'll have to use my pattern matching skills :)

Comment: I don't think this functionality exists, short of adding your own code to wrap the domain object that with *parse and return* it as a `List`. But this functionality doesn't exist because this is almost certainly a code smell. Having so many columns in one table to simply replicate these values kind of calls for another Table to store them.